# CSS Top and Left position not working in IE

Tags: javascript, css, html

Any workaround on top and left positioning in IE? Everything seems find in chrome but when I tried to run my page on IE, I observed that the top and left positioning is not working in IE.

Here is what I have so far.

```
<div data-notify="container" class="bootstrap-notify-container alert alert-dismissible bg-black p-r-35 animated fadeInDown" role="alert" data-notify-position="top-center" style="display: inline-block; margin: 0px auto; position: fixed; transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; z-index: 1031; top: 20px; left: 0px; right: 0px;">
                <span data-notify="icon"></span>
                <span data-notify="title"></span>
                <span data-notify="message">SAMPLE NAME HERE</span>
                <a href="#" target="_blank" data-notify="url"></a>
            </div>
```

[Here is a fiddle for my complete codes.](https://jsfiddle.net/mvks3pgf/)

Comment: What are you seeing? I just tested the Fiddle in Chrome and IE11 and they look the same. Is this a lower version of IE you are using?

Comment: @crazymatt Tested it out with lower version, doesn't work.

Comment: @crazymatt Im on IE edge and also tested it out with lower version and still not displaying the same with the chrome.

Comment: What do you mean "lower"? How much lower? Please [edit] your question to say exactly which version(s) of IE you're using.

Comment: @nnnnnn Im using edge and tested it out with IE 10 and 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Add this style it will work

or one demo here http://codepen.io/Bhupinderkumar/pen/ZerVyw

```
<div data-notify="container align-center" class="bootstrap-notify-container alert alert-dismissible bg-black p-r-35 animated fadeInDown" role="alert" data-notify-position="top-center" style="display: flex;justify-content:center; margin: 0px auto; transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; z-index: >
                <span data-notify="icon"></span>
                <span data-notify="title"></span>
                <span data-notify="message">SAMPLE NAME HERE</span>
                <a href="#" target="_blank" data-notify="url"></a>
            </div>
```

and if you need with position fixed you can use this one:

```
<div data-notify="container" class="bootstrap-notify-container alert alert-dismissible bg-black p-r-35 animated fadeInDown" role="alert" data-notify-position="top-center" style="display: inline-block; margin: 0px auto; position: fixed; transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; z-index: 1031; top: 20px; left: 0px; right: 0px;position:fixed;">
                <span data-notify="icon"></span>
                <span data-notify="title"></span>
                <span data-notify="message">SAMPLE NAME HERE</span>
                <a href="#" target="_blank" data-notify="url"></a>
            </div>
```

Comment: still not working in IE. But when I tried to run in chrome it seems find.

Comment: which version you are using its working fine for me in both browser http://codepen.io/Bhupinderkumar/pen/ZerVyw you can also do like this

Comment: fixed please check it

Comment: Tried to check it but the position is supposed to be at the top of my page your solution is close but the position is still not on the right place. It should be at the top of my page that's why I put top:0, left:0, right:0.

Comment: you can push position fixed as i give you another code. please add that it will work fine then

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the `left: 0px; right: 0px;`. It seems like it is supposed to be in two places at the same time, and so IE is confused, and supposedly breaks. Is there a reason you want to do that?

Comment: I just want to display it on the top of my page. And to display the same on how chrome render the style. Any ideas or workaround? Thank you.

Comment: Specifying a `left` *and* a `right` isn't confusing, it just means "put the left of the element at 0px from the left of the container, and put the right of the element at 0px from the right. It only gets confusing if you *also* specify a width.

Comment: @nnnnnn And a `max-width` is specified, so now things are getting confusing.

Comment: The element has seven classes *and* inline styles. I don't think there's any getting away from confusing here...

Comment: @nnnnnn Yeah, I don't use inline styles because it does get pretty confusing. I prefer having them in a class or an id instead.

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps!

```
<div data-notify="container" class="bootstrap-notify-container 
 alert alert-dismissible bg-black p-r-35 animated fadeInDown" 
 role="alert" data-notify-position="top-center" 
 style="display: inline-block; margin: 0px auto; 
 position: fixed; transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
 z-index: 1031; top: 20px; left:00px; right: 0px;
 margin-right:50px; margin-left:50px;">
                <span data-notify="icon"></span>
                <span data-notify="title"></span>
                <span data-notify="message">SAMPLE NAME HERE</span>
                <a href="#" target="_blank" data-notify="url"></a>
            </div>
```